# How to convert Uint8Array to image

Tags: javascript, jszip, uint8array

i am working on a project that has multi image upload option with zip. I open the zip through JSZip and inside there is a compressed content which is contain Uint8Array, but all my attemps to convert it to Blob or new Image failed.

My original plan was convert the images in zip to canvas element and add a watermark on them then compile the new images in a array before post to the api. So i am here and stuck miserably for two days.

```
chapterUpload(e) {
  let files = e.target.files[0],
      zip = new JSZip();

  zip.loadAsync(files).then(
    (zip) => {
      let zipValues = Object.values(zip.files);

      for (let i = 0; i < zipValues.length; i++) {
        let { compressedContent } = zipValues[i]._data,
            blob = new Blob([compressedContent], { type: "image/jpeg" }),
            url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);  // throws "The image cannot be displayed because it contains errors"

        this.zipImages.push(compressedContent);
      }

      console.log(this.zipImages); // this output right below
    },
    () => {
      alert("Please, upload a zip. (example.zip)");
    }
  );
},
```

Basically, i dont know how to covert the Uint8Array to normal decompressed image.

[Console log 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEGiS.png) [Console log 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sbjV.png)

Comment: Compare the length of the Uint8Arrays to the file sizes of the images: you're trying to create an image from the *compressed* file's bytes, not the original image's bytes.

Comment: I think you are iterating over the zip entries correctly but you need another (async?) step to uncompress the individual zip values... probably zipValues[i].async("blob", blob -> ...)

Comment: You need to get a file object first, then call async on it: https://jsfiddle.net/82kfvj1u/

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you so much, especially for the example code. If you share this below i like to select it as an answer.

Comment: @StefanHaustein Thank you so much for help, sir!